# How do i get a field to auto update when another field is filled in?

Tags: ms-access

I have a question with the following setup, i'm trying to auto populate one of the fields which i would then have to later use the value in the field to update into my database table. e.g shown in the picture below

As of current i have a query to pull out the details automatically from record 1 the moment i enter the form.

the values that come from the database currently are ProductID and Qty.

[image]

Anyone can run me through how i should progress from here? need to refresh my memory on this as its been quite awhile since i worked on Access related programming.

Update:
Thanks Perkins for pointing out that i was pretty vague.

My table basically contains ProductID(short text) and Qty(numbers) from the 2 fields shown in the the image.

The ProductID has a relation to my product detail page but i was doing up the function on inventory management on this side, i wanted to show the users that the current stock available(Qty) and also the total stock(total Quantity) after new stock(Unbound)is added to the inventory.

Firstly i would like to update the total quantity field after i off focus the (Unbound) text box, what i've done so far wasn't working.

Secondly once clicking update i would like to update the Qty in the database with the total Quantity(i have a rough idea of how to do this).

Codes on the Button update are as follows:

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_Command27_Click


    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70

Exit_Command27_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command27_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command27_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Really should not save this calculated value. It should be calculated when needed. Net stock balance should be calculated from incoming and outgoing transactions. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: June7's advice should be seriously considered, but may require changing your database schema. Regarding your specific situation, you need to share more detail.  You take care to tell us about some specific fields and show us a screen shot, but then you just say "updates value... into database" without any details about the table or fields you want to update.

Comment: Hi June and Perkins thanks for the replies, i further elaborated on the issue that i'm facing. still trying to figure out

Comment: If form is bound to record, can simply: `Me!fieldname = Me.textboxname`. If form is not bound to record then use INSERT or UPDATE sql actions to save/edit data to table. The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into.

Comment: Hi June7 Thanks for the speedy response, i managed to do the update by putting the value in the vba as per what you mention above. Another question is that how do i refresh the Total Qty textbox real time the moment i enter the value into the unbound field?

Comment: The Total Quantity should automatically calculate and 'refresh' when pressing Enter or Tab in the unbound control after entering a value. However, I don't think you will get the results you want. You want to update the Qty value by adding the QtyIn to it and saving that result then the expression will show that saved Qty added to the value currently in the unbound control, effectively showing it added a second time. You should probably set the unbound control back to Null or 0 after the Qty value is updated. I still recommend you NOT save aggregate data.